# Find records with the same relationships

Tags: mysql

Say I have Orders and Products.
For a given Order I want to find all the other orders that are made up of the exact same products.
So the schema would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
    id int
    ...
)
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id int,
    name text
)
CREATE TABLE OrderProduct (
    OrderId int,
    ProductId int
)
```

Consider the following data.

```
Order| Product
1|Burger
1|Drink
1|Fries
2|Burger
2|Drink
3|Burger
4|Burger
5|Burger
5|Drink
5|Fries
```

The desired query would return a list of every order that has the exact same products:

```
Where order ID -> Returned Result rows
1-> 1
    5
2-> 2
3-> 3
    4
4-> 3
    4
5-> 1
    5
```

Everything I have come up with so far requires ugly queries, multiple steps and knowing how many products will belong to an order up front.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be using `Group_Concat()` to stuff all the products for each order into one line, then match up all of the orders that have the same products and use `Group_Concat()` again to stuff all of *them* into the same line. See example:

```
Select `cte`.`Order` As `Queried order`, 
    Group_Concat(`cte2`.`Order` Order By `cte2`.`Order`) As `Returned Orders`
  From (
    Select `Order`, 
        Group_Concat(`Product` Order By `Product` Asc) As `Products`
      From `Table1`
      Group By `Order`) As `cte`
  Join (
    Select `Order`, 
        Group_Concat(`Product` Order By `Product` Asc) As `Products`
      From `Table1`
      Group By `Order`) As `cte2` On `cte`.`Products` = `cte2`.`Products`
  Group By `cte`.`Order`
;
```

This may be ugly, but it doesn't require multiple steps, or knowing the number of products up front.

**Edit**
Should be easier to get the output that you now describe. Just remove the final `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
Select `cte`.`Order` As `Queried order`, 
    `cte2`.`Order` As `Returned Order`
  From (
    Select `Order`, 
        Group_Concat(`Product` Order By `Product` Asc) As `Products`
      From `Table1`
      Group By `Order`) As `cte`
  Join (
    Select `Order`, 
        Group_Concat(`Product` Order By `Product` Asc) As `Products`
      From `Table1`
      Group By `Order`) As `cte2` On `cte`.`Products` = `cte2`.`Products`
;
```

Comment: Thanks, returns the literal result I had in the question, but not quite what I meant. I have updated the question.
The result should really only have one column and a row for each matching order id. I was hoping to avoid group concat but maybe it is necessary.